# Is validates_uniquness_of validating on updates and create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find at which action `validates_uniquness_of` in rails is validating? Is it on `new` or on `save`?

... meaning will it validate on update too or just create?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I might have found it myself:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark

As I can read it the answer is:

```
create
create!
save
save!
update
update!
```